# Python + Asyncio. Правильно ли проектирую первую асинхронную программу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, асинхронность, asyncio

Начинаю изучать асинхронное программирование. Пожалуйста подскажите в правильном ли направлении продвигаюсь при проектировании программы? 
Допустим, у меня есть несколько работников и класс TaskManager. Я хочу что бы они выполняли задания - говорили свое имя с ожиданием асинхронно. Правильно ли выглядит программа при таком раскладе?

```
import asyncio

class TaskManager:
    async def print_name(self, name):
        print('My name is', name)
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        print('My name is again', name)

workers = ['Dima', 'Vlad', 'Misha', 'Vova']
tm = TaskManager()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
tm.print_name(workers[0]),
tm.print_name(workers[1]),
tm.print_name(workers[2]),
tm.print_name(workers[3])
))
```

Вывод:

```
My name is Vlad
My name is Vova
My name is Misha
My name is Dima

My name is again Vlad
My name is again Misha
My name is again Vova
My name is again Dima
```

И бонусный вопрос - как мне передать в конструкцию `loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather())` Все значения списка одновременно? При переборе в цикле каждого в отдельности это не будет ведь асинхронным кодом) Большое спасибо всем заранее за объяснение!

Ps не понимаю почему всегда одна и та же последовательность имен в выводе. Почему не с 0 начинает? =)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для обработки списков используй map (или reduce для получения скаляра, но там посложнее). Изобретать таск менеджер в первой программе не стоит.

```
workers = ['Dima', 'Vlad', 'Misha', 'Vova']

async def print_name(name):
        print('My name is', name)
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        print('My name is again', name)


tasks =  map(print_name, workers)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
```

В таком виде обычный `map` вернет список корутин. Тут и передача списка тасков "через звездочку".

Последовательность одна и та же потому что зпускаются функции в порядке их запуска. Асинхронный запуск это не параллельный. Функции кладутся в очередь и запускаются из неё по порядку. Если в функции встречается `await` то её выполнение прерывается и запускаестся следующая функция из очереди до тех пор пока не будет готов ответ на тот `await`.